# Is a Constant Function Periodic with Infinite Number of Periods?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

This recently came up to me, can a constant function be considered periodic in a sense that it has infinite number of periods since

$$f(x+k)=c=f(x)$$ for $k\in(-\infty,\infty)$ ?

If this were true, for the graph of $f(x)$ to remain a straight line everywhere, the frequency of the function must be reaching infinity (invalidating the claim that there are infinite number of periods) with an amplitude that approaches $0$. How do I make sense out of this

Comment: Even the function $ \cos$ and $\sin $ has an infinite number of "period." but if I remember the definition well the period is the min of this set of $k$